# Provide dependencies of RPM for offline install

Tags: dependencies, rpm, rpmbuild

I've produced an RPM which will be installed on air-gapped PCs (it will be distributed via CD and USB). It requires newer versions of some third-party packages than is currently installed on some of the machines.

I need this to be installable by end-users and I'd prefer not to give them instructions which list many RPMs they have to manually install in a specific order.

Is there any way I can put these third-paty RPMs in a subfolder on the CD/USB, and make this location visible to the dependency resolver? Could I create a local repo in the %pre step of my .spec file and remove it in %post?

Comment: You might be able to setup a yum repository using a `file://` url rather than `http://`

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your comment. This seems like the right sort of track, but I'm struggling to work out how to get the location at the point of install - `pwd` just points to root unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking in `%pre` and `%post`, because (a) those are executed at install time which is well after dependency resolution and (b) you wouldn't be able to call `rpm` to install things from your `%pre` because the database is locked for the transaction you are part of.

When I've done something like this in the past, I have found the easiest thing to do is to put all the RPMs in a single directory on the media and instruct the deployment team to `yum localinstall *rpm` from that directory. If some of the third-party RPMs are older than what is installed, it will just skip over them.